# Reading output from yahoofinancials

Tags: python

How to read the output from yahoofinancials 1.5 ref. [https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/]
I'm new to Python, and need help to address the returned JSON Data output from:

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials  
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')  
print(yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income'))**
```

first few lines of non ordered output:

```
{'incomeStatementHistory': {'AAPL': [{'2019-09-28': {'researchDevelopment': 16217000000, 'effectOfAccountingCharges': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 65737000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 55256000000, 'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 18245000000, 'grossProfit': 98392000000, 'ebit': 63930000000, 'operatingIncome': 63930000000, 'otherOperatingExpenses': None, 'incomeBeforeTax': 65737000000, 'minorityInterest': None, 'netIncome': 55256000000, . . .  . .}
```

My output is with single quotes and not double quotes as expected, but contain all 4 year, OK.

I can address a single year by:

```
data = yahoofinancials.getfinancial_stmts('annual', 'income')   
data['incomeStatementHistory']['DSV.CO'][0]
```

get ordered output key value in each line:

```
{'2018-12-31': {'researchDevelopment': None'effectOfAccountingCharges': None,   
  'incomeBeforeTax': 5201000000,   
  'minorityInterest': -29000000,   
  'netIncome': 4000000000,   
  'sellingGeneralAdministrative': 11301000000,   
  'grossProfit': 17489000000,   
'ebit': 5426000000,   
'operatingIncome': 5426000000,   
'otherOperatingExpenses': None,   
'interestExpense': -355000000,   
'extraordinaryItems': None,   
'nonRecurring': None,   
'otherItems': None,   
'incomeTaxExpense': 1213000000,   
'totalRevenue': 79053000000,     
'totalOperatingExpenses': 73627000000,   
'costOfRevenue': 61564000000,   
'totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet': -225000000,   
'discontinuedOperations': None,   
'netIncomeFromContinuingOps': 3988000000,   
'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares': 4000000000}}
```

Here I want to adress a few single data items, but nothing works for me. Please help.

When I try to address 'ebit':

```
    data['incomeStatementHistory']['DSV.CO'][0]['ebit']
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                      Traceback (most recent call last)   
ipython-input-12-66fa46d51257> in module>   

-----> 1 data['incomeStatementHistory']['DSV.CO'][0]['ebit']

KeyError: 'ebit'
```

I also want to get EBITDA, where do I get it?   It is included from Yahoo.

I can get a few single data-items by: get_total_revenue() and get_net_income(), but only from the last year.  Can it be made to take year and or quorter as a parameter.

I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: how could you get `'DSV.CO'` if there is only `AAPL` ?

Comment: Thank you furas. DSV.CO is my favorit and I have called its data like AAPL. Problem solved. Your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you get in @PaulLo deleted answer - you can't get directly `ebit` because there is date like

```
 data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][0]['2019-09-28']['ebit']
 data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][1]['2019-09-29']['ebit']
 data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][2]['2019-09-30']['ebit']
```

But there can be different dates which you can see with `.keys()`

```
 print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][0].keys() ) # ['2019-09-28']
 print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][1].keys() ) # ['2019-09-29']
 print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][2].keys() ) # ['2019-09-30']
```

To resolve this problem you can use dates from `.keys()` or use `.items()` or `.values()`

```
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials  

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials('AAPL')
data = yahoo_financials.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'income') 

#print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][0].keys() ) # ['2019-09-28']
#print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][1].keys() ) # ['2019-09-29']
#print( data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL'][2].keys() ) # ['2019-09-30']

for item in data['incomeStatementHistory']['AAPL']:
    for key, val in item.items():
        print(key, val['ebit'])
```

Result:

```
2019-09-28 63930000000
2018-09-29 70898000000
2017-09-30 61344000000
2016-09-24 60024000000
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
from datetime import datetime
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbol = 'AAPL'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/financials?p=' + symbol

# Set up the request headers that we're going to use, to simulate
# a request by the Chrome browser. Simulating a request from a browser
# is generally good practice when building a scraper
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
}

# Fetch the page that we're going to parse, using the request headers
# defined above
page = requests.get(url, headers)

# Parse the page with LXML, so that we can start doing some XPATH queries
# to extract the data that we want
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

# Smoke test that we fetched the page by fetching and displaying the H1 element
tree.xpath("//h1/text()")

table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")

# Ensure that some table rows are found; if none are found, then it's possible
# that Yahoo Finance has changed their page layout, or have detected
# that you're scraping the page.
assert len(table_rows) > 0

parsed_rows = []

for table_row in table_rows:
    parsed_row = []
    el = table_row.xpath("./div")

    none_count = 0

    for rs in el:
        try:
            (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
            parsed_row.append(text)
        except ValueError:
            parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
            none_count += 1

    if (none_count < 4):
        parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)

df = pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)
df
```

Result:

```
                                              0  ...            5
0                                     Breakdown  ...    9/29/2016
1                                 Total Revenue  ...  215,639,000
2                               Cost of Revenue  ...  131,376,000
3                                  Gross Profit  ...   84,263,000
4                          Research Development  ...   10,045,000
5            Selling General and Administrative  ...   14,194,000
6                      Total Operating Expenses  ...   24,239,000
7                      Operating Income or Loss  ...   60,024,000
8                              Interest Expense  ...    1,456,000
9               Total Other Income/Expenses Net  ...   -1,195,000
10                            Income Before Tax  ...   61,372,000
11                           Income Tax Expense  ...   15,685,000
12            Income from Continuing Operations  ...   45,687,000
13                                   Net Income  ...   45,687,000
14  Net Income available to common shareholders  ...   45,687,000
15                                       EBITDA  ...   73,333,000
```